# Dfs Vs Bfs confusion

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

From a [topcoder article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-graphs-and-their-data-structures-section-2/):

> "In BFS We mark a vertex visited as we push it into the queue, not as
>   we pop it in case of DFS."

**NOTE:** This is said in case of dfs implementation using explicit stack.(pseudo dfs).

My question is why so? why we can not mark a vertex visited after popping from queue, instead while pushing onto the queue in case of bfs ?

Comment: Do you know how BFS differs from DFS? There is quite a difference in the order of the nodes being visited if you look at the Wikipedia pages for each.

Comment: @ JB King  Yes I know. Here I am asking it only in case of BFS . with some  examples I found that both the method (mark visited after popping from queue or mark visited before pushing onto the queue) gives the same result (level wise traversal). So why select the method mentioned in the article not the other one?

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-graphs-and-their-data-structures-section-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion probably comes from thinking about trees too much, but BFS and DFS can be run on any graph. Consider for example a graph with a loop like `A-B-C-A`. If you go breadth-first starting from `A`, you will first add B and `C` to the list. Then, you will pop `B` and, unless they were marked as visited, you will add `C` and `A` to the list, which is obviously wrong. If instead you go depth first from `A`, you will then visit `B` and from there go to `C` and then to `A`, unless `A` was already marked as visited.

So, in summary, you need to mark a vertex as seen as soon as you first see it, no matter which algorithm you take. However, if you only consider DAGs, you will find that things get a bit easier, because there you simply don't have any loop like the above. Anyway, the whole point is that you don't get stuck in a loop, and for that there are multiple variants. Setting a flag is one way, checking a set of visited vertices is another and in some cases like trees, you don't need to do anything but just iterate the edges in order.

Comment: "you need to mark a vertex as seen as soon as you first see it, no matter which algorithm you take.",so this is valid for DFS as well isn't?

Comment: Yes. You do this to set a stop sign for the case that you reach this vertex a second time due to a loop.